# Why do I have dollar-quote error on function with copy on postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions, dollar-quoting

I have a problem with a Postgres function with a COPY TO A CSV FILE, I have dollar-quote error

This is  the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_audit_deletions(IN table_name text) 
   RETURNS void AS 
   $body$ 
   DECLARE    
       interval INT; 
   BEGIN        
       COPY (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE backup = 1) 
          TO'/var/audiobays/logs/audit/table_name_deletions_(date-days).csv' CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER; 
    END 
    $body$ 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is the error

```
Error executing: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_audit_deletions(IN table_name text) RETURNS void AS
$body$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('COPY (SELECT * FROM %s WHERE backup = 1) TO ''/var/audiobays/logs/audit
.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 87 in SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_audit_deletions(IN table_name text) 
RETURNS void AS
$body$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('COPY (SELECT * FROM %s WHERE backup = 1) TO ''/var/audiobays/logs/audit
. Expected terminating $$
Error executing: END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 5 in SQL END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

. Expected terminating $$"
```

Comment: You are probably using the wrong client GUI then. Try something different.

Comment: Sorry Laurenz I don' t understand your answer

Comment: Can you include error message/hint/detail and when it occurs?

Comment: Some clients do not recognize dollar quoting. Does the error occur upon trying to `CREATE` the function? Try replacing the dollar quoting with single quotes `'`. Note: You will need to escape the quotes within the body of the function.

Comment: On monday I' ll post the error

Comment: I have posted the error @ŁukaszKamiński

Comment: I think it might be no semicolon after `END` tho I does not produce error for me. I was sure it was required there.

Comment: I ' ve tired but not is this the error, the error message is the same, but now position is 6 (where there is the semicolon).

Comment: Which SQL tool do you use to run that? `psql` or something different?

Comment: LANGUAGE plpgsql; Is this that want you know?

Comment: now I have edited my function and I have used another sintax                   
 "\copy (SELECT * FROM %s WHERE backup = 1) TO concat('/var/audiobays/logs/audit/', table_name, '_deletions_(', date-days, ').csv');"  But it doesn' t work

Comment: No, what application you used to execute that query - pgAdmin, psql, phpPgAdmin, DBeaver, some code in programming language using library XYZ to connect to PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have a file test_db.sql where I write my functions and I execute theese functions on SQLWorkbench @ŁukaszKamiński. Sorry but I'm not an expert

Comment: I just tested it in SQL Workbench/J and it works fine. Can you post full CREATE statement from error message? It clearly is different from what you shown as failing statement.

Comment: Hi, @ŁukaszKamiński now it works for me in the workbench but if I use || to concat the values to create the path ì, there Is a syntax error on ||. This is the path '/var/audiobays/logs/audit/' || table_name || '_deletions_(date-days).csv'